# Solr 6.6: How to define fields to store multiple slug variation for one posts?

Tags: solr

We have tasks to find posts by various type of slugs:

```
posts/state
posts/city-name
posts/city-name/category
posts/city-name/category/subcategory
posts/long-title-slug
posts/category
posts/... what our seo expert want
```

We have all posts stored in mariadb and on change we push data to SOLR or delete from. While seo tasks grooving, we need to store all seo links in SOLR. We have unknown number of seo variations per posts.

We need to define fields to store multiple slug variation for one posts. How to?

UPDATE current SOLR Schema

```
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title" type="text" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="facet_title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="facet_title_length" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="slug" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="company_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="logo" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="cpc" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="date" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="location" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="city" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="postalcode" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="address" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="industry" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="externalid" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="externalurl" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>

  <field name="premium" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" default="false"/>
  <field name="source" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="created" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="modified" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="hits" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Comment: What’s the problem here? Save all multiple slugs in a multivalue field?

Comment: @Mysterion yes, thats is problem, while i not have experience.

Comment: So, how you're doing indexing in solr right now?

Comment: We have php background task to push data to our external solr server (schema added to question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `slug` field multiValued:

```
<field name="slug" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

.. and store all possible slug variations there. If you're only storing `long-title-slug` in that field today and would like to keep it that way, add a new field instead:

```
<field name="path_slug" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

.. and then include all possible values for the slugs there as an array.

```
['posts/state', 'posts/city-name', ....]
```

Exactly how you do that depends on the code you're using to submit content to Solr, but all Solr libraries support this in some way - either by making multiple calls to `addField` or similar, or giving an array to the `addField` method.

You can then query on that slug by using `path_slug:posts/state`.